# Unqualified-id before 'using'

Tags: c++11

I want to define the following alias into the namespace Library:

```
namespace Library
{
    template <typename T>
    using MyVector = std::vector<T, std::allocator<T> >;
}
```

but I get the following error from the compiler:

```
expected unqualified-id before 'using'
```

I'm following [the official reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) on cppreference.com but so far I couldn't make it work. What am I missing?

Comment: And you do build with C++11 enabled? What compiler are you using? What version of it? What flags or options are you setting?

Comment: I'm using Eclipse Neon. This is the compile command run:
    g++ "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\CFITSIO\\include" "-IC:\Users\Enzo\workspace\Boost\include" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o main.o "..\main.cpp"

Comment: Then C++11 is not enabled. You need to add the `-std=c++11` option to the build command. I don't know how that is done in Eclipse.

Comment: You were right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/some-programmer-dude) got it: C++11 was not set.
To set the proper dialect go to: Project->Properties->C/C++ Build->Settings->Tool Settings->GCC C++ Compiler->Dialect->Language Standard->ISO C++ 11